# Gwt celltable : Unexpected behavior : when record deleted from page then other record repeated in page

Tags: gwt, grid, gwt-2.2-celltable, gwt-celltable

I am using celltable -- gwt2.3.
I found strange behavior in celltable.
My celltable's pagesize is 10. Total 13 records.
When Page contains 3 records
A 1 11
B 2 22
C 3 33

When I deleted any one record e.g. A record then that record is deleted from page but other record repeated / sets in page.
i.e.
B 2 22
C 3 33
C 3 33
Page is trying to set 3 recods some how.
Expected 2 records in page after deleting 1 record

I also called

- updateRowData(startIndexOfPage, recordList);
- updateRowCount(updatedRecordCount, true);

Still same issue :-|

Whats wrong ? How to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does your data look like for rows 4-13?  You should not expect 2 records in a page after you delete a row - the page size won't change unless you explicitly change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**//Set the complete list of values to display on one page.**

```
cellTable.setRowData(listOfRecord); // This solved my problem
```